# ASP.NET 6 + React APIs

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have been struggling to integrate React with ASP.NET 6

Finally I am using the following configuration at `Program.cs`

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "FrontEnd";

    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

and had `WDS_SOCKET_PORT=7207` in the `.env.development` file of the frontend to refresh the page with every code update

Now my problem is that all APIs respond with `404` (it worked previously very well as WebAPI app without React)

I don't think that I am pointing to a wrong port, knowing that I am using the port the is in `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7207"`

I think the routing configuration needs to be adjusted

Can't solve it

====

AS requested here is the `Program.js`

```
using EBankingSystem.Data;
using EBankingSystem.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.
// DB
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("Development")));
services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// View
In production, the React files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
   configuration.RootPath = "FrontEnd/build";
});

// Controllers
services.AddControllers();

// Identity
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();


app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "FrontEnd";

    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Did you check your api port from ```Properties/launchsettings.json```?

Comment: Yes I did. As mentioned

Comment: Please provide all code from `Program.cs`, so we can see full configuration.

Comment: Try to move `app.useSpa` after `app.MapControllers`

Comment: Tried but falied also